# SQL about updating one table based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table A with following columns/data

```
SECURITY PURCHASEDATE    NAICRating   NAICDate 
 XX        10/12/2013
 YY        10/14/2013
```

and table B as follows

```
SECURITY  NAICRating   NAICDate
  XX        AA         10/12/2013
  XX        AAA        10/13/2013
  XX        AA         10/14/2013
  YY        AA         10/15/2013
  YY        B          10/16/2013
```

I now want the table A to get the NAICRating from B for the earliest NAICdate on or after the PURCHASEDATE  in table A

The table A should look as follows

```
SECURITY PURCHASEDATE    NAICRating   NAICDate 
 XX        10/12/2013      AA          10/12/2013
 YY        10/14/2013      AA          10/15/2013
```

What is the best way to achieve this using MySQL?

Comment: show your database model in better way

Comment: I used cursor but it is very slow..

Answer (score 0):

The inner join will only show records when they exist in both tables.

```
select a.security, 
       IF(a.purchasedate < b.naicrating, a.purchasedate, b.naicrating), 
       b.naicrating, 
       IF(a.purchasedate < b.naicdate, a.purchasedate, b.naicdate)
from a inner join b on a.security = b.security
order by naicdate;
```

This can help with the IF statement http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx

Comment: Will your Suggestion miodify table A. It may give me the output i need but i also want to modify table A

Comment: Are you trying to replace A's Dates with table B's dates if B's date is sooner?

Comment: You could create a view of the query and keep your tables intact.

Comment: Not if sooner .Only if NAICDate >= PurchaseDate get the earliest such date

Comment: I need to change the table A so creating a view will not help

Comment: you could add an IF statement in the select